# How to use JavaScript variable outside of the function in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to assign a value to variable within the function and then use it outside of the function but can't make it work:

```
var data;

function assign(value) {
  data = value
}

var post = {
  content: [
    { text: data } // variable is used outisde of the function
  ]
}

console.log(data) // data is undefined outisde the assign function!
```

Comment: You didn't call assign

Comment: Make `text` a function:  `{ text: () => data }` or assign `value` to `post.content[0].text` or use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy)

Comment: This may be related to [this](/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: This type of structure of using a higher scoped variable that is set in a function is usually code smell (bad code).  Usually, the function should just return its result, not set it into a higher scoped variable.  Or use a class/object and set instance data via a method.  And, when used with asynchronous operations (which is often what people try to do), it won't work at all because the code outside the function will never know when the asynchronous operation has completed and the value has now been set.